# bumblebee 64 and 32 bit?

Tags: apt, bumblebee, primus

Is it possible to have bumblebee and primus 64 bit and 32 bit both installed at the same time? So that 64bit apps will use the 64bit libs?

If so, how?

When I  sudo apt-get install primus:i386, it tells me it's going to remove the 64 bit versions.

Thanks!

UPDATE: Here's what I'm getting when I run: primerun steam or optirun steam
Running Steam on ubuntu 15.10 64-bit
STEAM_RUNTIME is enabled automatically
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(1446742416)
assert_20151114115841_1.dmp[11632]: Uploading dump (out-of-process)
/tmp/dumps/assert_20151114115841_1.dmp
/home/me/.local/share/Steam/steam.sh: line 756: 11621 Segmentation fault      (core dumped) $STEAM_DEBUGGER "$STEAMROOT/$STEAMEXEPATH" "$@"
assert_20151114115841_1.dmp[11632]: Finished uploading minidump (out-of-process): success = yes
assert_20151114115841_1.dmp[11632]: response: CrashID=bp-6292283e-e5e0-4d07-b211-bc29a2151114
assert_20151114115841_1.dmp[11632]: file ''/tmp/dumps/assert_20151114115841_1.dmp'', upload yes: ''CrashID=bp-6292283e-e5e0-4d07-b211-bc29a2151114''

Comment: Do you have nvidia graphics card in your hardware ?

Comment: Yes. It's the new Dell XPS 15 (9550)
Running optirun glxinfo | grep OpenGl works. Gimp etc work. But Steam and possibly blender need 32bit libs.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't install primus:i386 but **primus-libs:i386** and **primus-libs-ia32:i386**

Also installing **primus** alone should install those packages by default!

```
sudo apt-get install primus
```

works for me with both 32-bit (Steam, TF2 etc.)

and 64-bit apps (Blender, War Thunder etc.)!